# How to open react-dropzone-uploader input file programatically? - React, Typescript, React-dropzone-uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dropzone

I want to trigger `react-dropzone-uploader` input file dialog using an `onClick`. Does anyone know how can I do this? I've been searching since last week until finally decided to ask here for chances of being answered. Would really appreciate it. Thank you.